# Real time instagram api

Tags: php, instagram-api

Real time instagram api does not callback when I post instagram to `callback.php`

This one is a list subscription

```
Array (
  [meta] => Array ( [code] => 200 )
  [data] => Array ([0] => 
    Array (
      [object] => user
      [object_id] =>
      [aspect] => media
      [callback_url] => http://sandbox.xxx.info/instagram/callback.php 
      [type] => subscription
      [id] => 17368472
    )
  )
)
```

In my `callback.php` I just try to writ something into file

```
$data['x'] = '1234';
$file = file_get_contents('tmp/test.php');
$fulldata = $file . "\n\n" . json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('tmp/test.php', $fulldata);
```

but nothing happen after I post photo in my instagram.

Comment: Is it OK not to provide the `object_id` here?

Comment: I saw in the User subscriptions object_id can be null.